# Addon in Whats App

Tags: android, whatsapp

I am trying to put an additional button on what's app. Is there any possible way to install `add ons` on the whats app and perform the functionality from custom built apps. I tried to google alot but could not find any appropriate way of doing so. I would really appreciate if any body can give me any direction on how can I do so? Following is the app which works just like the way I am trying to do in whatsapp.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidsx.smileys

Comment: Look into mods - Whats App plus